# how to iterate over each single column of the chunk in python without using pandas?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two parts question for this

```
X = [[[-1.0, -1.0], [-2.0, -1.9], [-3.4, -2.0], [3.0, 1.5], [3.7, 1.0]], 
     [[3.0, 2.0]  , [-4.0, 10.0]], 
     [[-10.0, 5.0], [-6.0, -10.0]],
     [[2.0, -2.0]]]
```

first I wnat to iterate over every single column of the chunk ? How to do it?

this is my approach :

```
ds = zip(*X)
for list in ds:
  print(list)
```

but it's giving me only one column:
([-1.0, -1.0], [3.0, 2.0], [-10.0, 5.0], [2.0, -2.0])

second how to creat 2 points for each column?

Comment: What's your expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

Unclear what your expected output is but:

```
data = [
    [[-1.0, -1.0], [-2.0, -1.9], [-3.4, -2.0], [3.0, 1.5], [3.7, 1.0]],
    [[3.0, 2.0], [-4.0, 10.0]],
    [[-10.0, 5.0], [-6.0, -10.0]],
    [[2.0, -2.0]]
]

flattened = [column for row in data for column in row]
```

Output:

```
[[-1.0, -1.0],
 [-2.0, -1.9],
 [-3.4, -2.0],
 [3.0, 1.5],
 [3.7, 1.0],
 [3.0, 2.0],
 [-4.0, 10.0],
 [-10.0, 5.0],
 [-6.0, -10.0],
 [2.0, -2.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
for lst in zip_longest(*X):
    print(lst)
```

Output:

```
([-1.0, -1.0], [3.0, 2.0], [-10.0, 5.0], [2.0, -2.0])
([-2.0, -1.9], [-4.0, 10.0], [-6.0, -10.0], None)
([-3.4, -2.0], None, None, None)
([3.0, 1.5], None, None, None)
([3.7, 1.0], None, None, None)
```

If you don't want `None`s:

```
for lst in zip_longest(*X):
    print(lst[:(lst.index(None) if None in lst else None)])
```

---

```
([-1.0, -1.0], [3.0, 2.0], [-10.0, 5.0], [2.0, -2.0])
([-2.0, -1.9], [-4.0, 10.0], [-6.0, -10.0])
([-3.4, -2.0],)
([3.0, 1.5],)
([3.7, 1.0],)
```

Comment: how to create two data points for each column I want to make a data set size double the number of columns ?

Comment: @user4556432 Ask another question, I answered your original question, so you should upvote and mark this, and ask another question and I try to solve, because this comment is lack of info.

Comment: I've already asked it as a second question in this specific original question!

Comment: @user4556432 What do you mean by "I want to make a data set size double the number of columns ? "

Comment: I mean number of rows (data points) double the number features (columns)

Comment: @user4556432 Add to your question the expected output...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'every column'.  When I look at your nested list `X`, it seems to be a list of 2D nested lists each with 2 columns and a variable number of rows:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> [np.array(ch).shape for ch in X]
[(5, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2), (1, 2)]
```

In your question you describe the following as a column:

```
([-1.0, -1.0], [3.0, 2.0], [-10.0, 5.0], [2.0, -2.0])
```

This is the first row of each of the 2D arrays I describe above.  Since the last of these only has one row, the zip operation will stop after the first row because it runs out of items.

Maybe you are trying to concatenate all the 2D arrays into a vertical stack.

```
>>> np.vstack(X)
array([[ -1. ,  -1. ],
       [ -2. ,  -1.9],
       [ -3.4,  -2. ],
       [  3. ,   1.5],
       [  3.7,   1. ],
       [  3. ,   2. ],
       [ -4. ,  10. ],
       [-10. ,   5. ],
       [ -6. , -10. ],
       [  2. ,  -2. ]])
```

Or, if you don't want to use numpy, as @Lukas suggested:

```
>>> [row for chunk in X for row in chunk]
[[-1.0, -1.0],
 [-2.0, -1.9],
 [-3.4, -2.0],
 [3.0, 1.5],
 [3.7, 1.0],
 [3.0, 2.0],
 [-4.0, 10.0],
 [-10.0, 5.0],
 [-6.0, -10.0],
 [2.0, -2.0]]
```

Also, note that you should not use the Python keyword `list` as a variable.

Comment: thanks for explaining I want to create another set  such that size of the set is double the number of columns so how  to create two points for each column?

Comment: I'm still not clear what you mean by 'column'. It would help a lot if you just showed your expected output in the question (as @Psidom asked).